# How determine the proper version of an Android library?

Tags: android, android-studio, build, build.gradle, version

For example, I have a working module whose `build.gradle` file has

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
}
```

Where does this number "1.1.0" come from?  Where can I find a listing?

I want to add functionalities to it.  I see the list of AndroidX packages at

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/packages

but it provides no version numbers...

Answer (score 1):

Go to **File->Project Structure->Dependencies**

[image]

Now go to **Add->Library**

**Search Library and all version will show of selected library**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

- **The [official site](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/explorer)**
  Click on the library and check the doc
  [image]
- **[The google maven repo](https://maven.google.com/web/index.html)**
  [Search](https://maven.google.com/web/index.html?q=androidx.recyclerview) the library name and check the list
  [image]
- **File->Project Structure->Dependencies** as described in the [@Sandeep answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62971465/2016562)